# xml to a nested dictionary strucure

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Admin>
  <Name>function1</Name>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Value>True</Value>
  <Name>function2</Name>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Value>False</Value>
  .
  .
  .
  <Name>functionN</Name>
  <Id>N</Id>
  <Value>False</Value>
</Admin>
```

And I want to load this file into a dictionary structure like this:

```
Dictionary<AccessPoint, bool>
```

AccessPoint is a class:

```
public class AccessPoint
{
  public int    Id   { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I put every piece of the xml to the right place in shorter codes?

Here is what I did so far:

```
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path))
{
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(reader);

  XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.ChildNodes;

  foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
  {
    var xmlValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
      xmlValue[child.LocalName] = child.InnerText;
    }

    entityInfo.Add(xmlValue);

  }
}
```

But, the entityInfo only collects the last unit values of the xml file:

```
{[Value, False]}
{[Id, N]}
{[Name, FunctionN]}
```

Comment: I suggest you look into the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) classes. [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is also an option. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Or create your own dictionary type (extends `Dictionary<AccessPoint, bool>`) and implement the interface [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably write an XPath query to get what you want, but getting what you want is probably easier (more performant, too!) if you do something like this:

```
class AccessPoint
{
  public string Name  { get ; set ; }
  public int    Id    { get ; set ; }
  public bool   Value { get ; set ; }
}

static IEnumerable<AccessPoint> AccessPointsFromXml( XDocument doc )
{
  AccessPoint item = null ;

  foreach( XElement e in doc.Root.Elements() )
  {
    switch ( e.Name.LocalName )
    {
    case "Name" :
      if ( item != null ) yield return item ;
      item = new AccessPoint{ Name = e.Value , } ;
      break ;
    case "Id" :
      int id ;
      int.TryParse(e.Value,out id) ;
      if ( item == null ) item = new AccessPoint() ;
      item.Id = id ;
      break ;
    case "Value" :
      bool value ;
      bool.TryParse(e.Value,out value) ;
      if ( item == null ) item = new AccessPoint() ;
      item.Value = value ;
      break ;
    }
  }

  // take care of the last item (if there is one)
  if ( item != null ) yield return item ;

}
```

Then building your dictionary is easy:

```
string xml = @"
  <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
  <Admin>
    <Name>function1</Name>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Value>True</Value>
    <Name>function2</Name>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Value>False</Value>
    <Name>function3</Name>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Value>False</Value>
  </Admin>
  ".Trim() ;

XDocument                    doc  = XDocument.Load( new StringReader(xml) ) ;
Dictionary<AccessPoint,bool> dict = AccessPointsFromXml(doc)
                                    .ToDictionary( x => x , x => x.Value )
                                    ;
```

Edited to note:

Using `XmlDocument` instaed of `XDocument` doesn't change things much:

```
static IEnumerable<AccessPoint> AccessPointsFromXml( XmlDocument doc )
{
  AccessPoint item = null ;
  foreach( XmlElement e in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes )
  {
    switch ( e.LocalName )
    {
    case "Name" :
      if ( item != null ) yield return item ;
      item = new AccessPoint{ Name = e.InnerText } ;
      break ;
    case "Id" :
      int id ;
      int.TryParse(e.InnerText,out id) ;
      if ( item == null ) item = new AccessPoint() ;
      item.Id = id ;
      break ;
    case "Value" :
      bool value ;
      bool.TryParse(e.InnerText,out value) ;
      if ( item == null ) item = new AccessPoint() ;
      item.Value = value ;
      break ;
    }
  }
  if ( item != null ) yield return item ;
}
```

Something else to note: you might want to make your `AccessPoint` class implement `IComparable<AccessPoint>`, so your dictionary behaves more like you'd expect it to:

```
class AccessPoint : IComparable<AccessPoint>
{
  public string Name { get ; set ; }
  public int  Id { get ; set ; }
  public bool Value { get ; set ; }

  public int CompareTo( AccessPoint other )
  {
    int cc = other != null ? 0 : -1 ;
    if ( cc == 0 )
    {
      cc = String.Compare( this.Name , other.Name , StringComparison.Ordinal ) ;
    }
    if ( cc == 0 )
    {
      cc = this.Id.CompareTo( other.Id ) ;
    }
    return cc ;
  }
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format( "name={0}, id={1}, value={2}" , Name,Id,Value ) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Nicholas, it really broad my thought, and work like a charm! Big thanks!